# What's the correct way of setting properties with Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Suppose, we have 2 classes - `Main` and `MainDependency`. The second class is used only by `Main`, and the purpose of using IoC is constructing an instance of `Main` class.

`MainDependency` class has a field of integer type. This field is not required to be set (or, let's assume it should always have a default value if nothing else is specified).

The problem: what's the most correct way to set the integer field? One way I see is creating similar field inside my `Module` and then using that value inside `configure` module. But I feel it's a wrong way.

Please, share your experience. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mainly have two options:

1) Inject it using constant binding. The value of `MY_CONSTANT` could be passed to `Module` at instantiation time; could be taken from a system property, or maybe some other way.

```
class MainDependency{
  @Inject
  public MainDependency(@Named("myConst") int myConst){
    //...
  }
}

class Module extends AbstractModule{
  public void configure(){
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("myConst").to(MY_CONSTANT);
  }
}
```

2) Use assisted inject to create a factory which will take your value as a parameter and return an instance of `MainDependency`:

```
interface MainDependencyFactory{
  MainDependency create(int myConst);
}

class MainDependency{
  @Inject
  public MainDependency(@Assisted int myConst){
    //..
  }
}

class Module extends AbstractModule{
  public void configure(){
    bind(MainDependencyFactory.class).toProvider(
      FactoryProvider.newFactory(MainDependencyFactory.class, MainDependency.class));
  }
}

//to use the above, instantiate your factory (or inject it somewhere)
MainDependencyFactory f = injector.getInstance(MainDependencyFactory.class);
//Then you can create MainDependency with any value
MainDependency md = f.create(MY_CONSTANT);
```

Note that with assisted inject you don't need to implement `MainDependencyFactory`. Guice will create it for you.